# How to replace a word using python parser in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I have the names like below

- Rua Jose Rovira
- Travessa Jose Rovira
- Rua Antônio de Jose Belém

I need to replace the name José where the Jose.

I'm trying this:

```
!field!.replace("Jose","José")
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?

Comment: Using arcmap 10.3

Comment: error 000539, Unicode decode error

Comment: Unicode decode errors generally mean you are trying to process an unrecognized special character.